# hyperledger fabric make error :"goimports: command not found"

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

when I build make the hyperledger fabric project ,I have the following error.but I have install the goimports successfully. To find the reason, I run `./scripts/golinter.sh` alone, and there is no such error.what is the error reason,when I make the whole fabric project.

> LINT: Running code checks.. Checking ./accesscontrol
>   ./scripts/golinter.sh: line 23: goimports: command not found
>   Makefile:148: recipe for target 'linter' failed make: *** [linter]
>   Error 127

[image]

Answer (score 12):

If you are running go1.17 you may need to use `go install` instead of of `go get`:

```sh
go install golang.org/x/tools/cmd/goimports@latest
```

Comment: Go by default installed it in the $HOME directory. The following would specify the output directory.

#GOBIN=/usr/local/go/bin/ go install golang.org/x/tools
/cmd/goimports@latest

Answer (score 7):

In macOS:

```
vi ~/.bashrc
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/go/bin"
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 6):

goimports updates your Go import lines, adding missing ones and removing unreferenced ones. Its a tool which user need to

```
go get golang.org/x/tools/cmd/goimports
```

[Reference](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/goimports)

Answer (score 2):

I'm on Mac, I was able to make this work by including `$HOME/go/bin` in my path (`~/.bashrc`). Seems to be open in the documentation, something I missed

Answer (score 1):

When you run `./scripts/golinter.sh` directly, you are running it on your local system, hence it finds your locally installed `goimports` utility.

When you run `make` (or more specifically, `make linter`), the `golinter.sh` script is run inside a container based on the `hyperledger/fabric-buildenv` image. There must be some mismatch, so I recommend that you remove all traces of images tagged with `hyperledger/fabric-buildenv` and run `make buildenv` to create new images. Even better would be a `make clean` followed by `make`, since there are other images that build on top of `hyperledger/fabric-buildenv`.

Answer (score 0):

In Makefile

```
linter: buildenv
@echo "LINT: Running code checks.."
#add this
@echo "$(DOCKER_TAG)"
@$(DRUN) $(DOCKER_NS)/fabric-buildenv:$(DOCKER_TAG) ./scripts/golinter.sh
```

So you could find the docker image you're using to do the work.
it should be like this:

```
hyperledger/fabric-buildenv    x86_64-1.1.1-snapshot-cd36699   29266298cc73        3 minutes ago       1.43GB
```

And you could run it:

```
docker run -it 29266298cc73
#install the cmd in it
$go get golang.org/x/tools/cmd/goimports
```

And commit the container outside the container

```
docker container list
#find the container you just install the cmd,supose it's 3cbdd6e3c109
docker commit 3cbdd6e3c109 hyperledger/fabric-buildenv:x86_64-1.1.1-snapshot-cd36699
```

Now you could run the make again,and it should be ok now.

Anyway it's a bug for release1.1

Comment: What do you mean by "commit the container outside the container"? 'docker' command is not found inside fabric-buildenv. Also, 'docker ps' is empty after exiting fabric-buildenv.

Answer (score -1):

1. copy goimports to dir `fabric/build/image/buildenv/payload`
2. edit `images/buildenv/Dockerfile.in` and add `COPY payload/goimports usr/local/bin/` to it.

You can read Makefile and learn about the background.